# iframe weird behavior on 2nd load event

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a page with a single cross-domain iframe in it. The iframe shows a form and after submitting the form the view is changed to thank you page without changing the iframe source (iframe reloads). 
I have binded a load event to the iframe.

When the webpage first loads, browser loads the iframe also and the load event fires before rendering HTML inside the iframe. So technically load event fires first and then the HTML is rendered.

After submitting the form, the iframe reloads but renders all the HTML before firing the load event. During this second load time iframe load event fires after rendering the HTML.

My question is why does the load event fire before rendering html during the first load, but during the second load it fires after the html is rendered?

I want the load event to fire before rendering HTML in second time load also.

Comment: the first shown page has dynamic content/scripts, while the "thanks" page doesn't

Comment: Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: the load event fires when all the resources are fetched, but before scripts have a crack at "DHTML". If the scripts do a lot (especially fetching dynamic data from a server), there's a delay between load() and the apparent rendering. If the content is all static, there's no delay.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the load event is firing before html because the dynamic links/content take time to load, so technically load event does not fire before html, it's just because of the time taken by dynamic content/links?

Comment: If the content is static, it should still fire before rendering the HTML or should it not?
Is it normal to fire after rendering HTML in static content case or can we say it's a bug?

Comment: i think the load event is actually independent of the rendering; they typically happen about the same time though.